# Input from textbox and file in PHP form

Tags: javascript, php, html, shell

I have tried making a html and php page for taking input and processing them respectively. In the HTML page, user is given a option of either give a text or upload the file.

```
<form action="target.php" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data"            id="form">
<table  width="950px" align="center">
<tr>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  class="table1"  border="0">
<tr valign="middle" align="left"><td width="15" height="10"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr valign="middle" align="left">
<td width="15"></td>
<td><font  color="White">input1</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td width="15"></td>
<td>
<font color="Red"><input type="file" name="file" size="42"><br></font><font color="White">or paste below:</font><br>
<textarea name="sequence1" cols="96" rows="7"></textarea><br>     
</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
</table> </form>
```

Similarly in the PHP page, i could succesfuly transfer the uploaded file from the html page to a varible and run the shell script but unable to process the content from textbox.

```
<?php
$a = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$c = (isset($_POST['sequence1'])) ? $_POST['sequence1'] : false;
if($a!=NULL)
{
$output=shell_exec("sh server.sh $a");
 }
elseif ($c!=NULL){
$output=shell_exec("sh server.sh $c");}
else{
echo "No input";}
?>
```

Can anybody help me to solve this problem or other way you could help me would be text input variable to converted to a file for the shell script

Comment: as minimum your form tag isn't closed

Comment: `$a` needs ternary assignment on the `isset()`. You cannot echo `no input` without encapsulating it as a string with `'` or `"`

Comment: `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` Yeah, who needs CSS anyways.

Comment: @VladNikitin: I have given a part of the form and So it was not appeared. I have closed it in the original form.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I have tried to give the ternary assignment isset(), but did not really help me in the code!!..minor changes were made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, this is what you need to do:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sequence1'])){
    //get the input content
    $textInput = $_POST['sequence1'];
    //temp file name
    $file = 'temp.txt';
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $textInput);
    $output=shell_exec("sh server.sh $file");
}else{
    echo "No input";
}
?>
```

Comment: This is not working!!..Since the shell script i have written takes the file names as the argument.!!

Comment: When i upload the files through the html form, they were processes perfectly without anyproblem.BUt when i give the same data pasted in the textbox of the form. It doesn't give me a output. The most probabily reason i have understood is shell script i have written takes the argument as file name not directly the text. Actually i need help to make this textinput to be stored in a temp file and given to shell script!!.. I hope this will make you clear!!

Comment: I have tried this but shell script is not taking it. May be the path need to be defined. I have tried to echo the $file and it gives the temp.txt which means the text is into the file but the shell script is not able to find the path of the file to take it as a input

Comment: @RamT Things to check, make sure **a)** `temp.txt` gets created with the content **b)** make sure `server.sh` and the `temp.txt` are in the same directory **c)** you can store the command in a variable and `echo $cmd` **d)** if all the above is done copy and run the command directly into the server

Answer (score 0):

Parse error in your php code.

```
  echo No input;
```

It should be

```
echo "No input";
```